# Recommendations for a Java IRC client library that supports Socks proxies?

Tags: java, irc

I'm looking for a decent Java IRC client library that supports connecting to an IRC server through a socks proxy.  Any recommendations?

Comment: The JDK has built-in support for SOCKS proxies. So, really, it's not hard to make any open-source IRC library use it. :-)

Comment: Right, but so far as I'm aware, the JDK only supports forcing *all* outbound TCP connections through a SOCKS proxy, which isn't acceptable for my use-case.  I have one outbound IRC connection which must go through a SOCKS proxy, but then I have several other TCP connections connecting to localhost, which must not go through the SOCKS proxy.  Any ideas?

Comment: No, Java provides the ability to have individual sockets use a socks proxy, so all you need to do is find an irc library that lets you set up the socket first.

Comment: nos, ok - any recommendations for one of those?  PircBot doesn't seem to support it :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost","{proxy host IP}");
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort","{proxy port}");
```

just before you open the IRC connection and then

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", null);
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", null);
```

after the connection has been established to undo it. That SHOULD work for even PircBot.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Ah, very clever (although a shame that Java/PircBot force us to resort to such hackery).